# TFS 2015 Build Steps - cache info from one step to another

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

we use the new vNext Build system. I have several steps in my build defintion - example:

Step 1 executes a PowerShell-Script to determine the dynamic path to a specific setup file. How can I save ("cache") this path to use it in step 2. It does not work when I cache this information in an variable (eg "$Env:SetupPathVE")

thx..!

Comment: Something similar has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881749/is-it-possible-to-set-an-vso-build-variable-in-a-build-step-so-that-the-value-ca). Besides, [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/375) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/559) issues on Github give more information.

Comment: sorry I'm little bit confused

so... I use this command in my first PowerShell-Script:

`Write-Host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]"D:test"`

and then I can use this variable in the FileCopy-Step with `$(testvar)` in the Source Field ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the way it works in VSO now. However, on premise TFS 2015 RTM does not have this functionality. On premise you can still set the variable value like that, then it turns into ALLCAPS environment variable which you can read **inside** of the next build step. For instance, in the following PowerShell step you'll be able to read your `testvar` as `$env:TESTVAR`

Comment: sorry Yan. I've tested it extensively and it does not work with the current 'on premise' version of TFS (Version 14.0.23128.0)

Comment: @Kollisionskurs have you been able to solve this already? Can you show us the content of your scripts so we can help debug?