# How To set Azure pipeline variable from PowerShell

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am trying to set the Azure pipeline variable value in PowerShell. I have created one variable `winversion` in the Azure pipeline. Now, in a PowerShell task, I want to assign some values to the `winversion` variable.
My simple question is how can I change the value of an Azure PipeLine variable at run time?

```
Write-Host "Main value is $winversion"
$env:WINVERSION="abhinav";
Write-Host "Modified value is $env:WINVERSION"
Write-Host "Main value is $(winversion)"
```

Firstline print: original value is 123
Thirdline Print: Modified value is abhinav
Fourth Line print: 123

I want when I change the value of winversion from "123" to "abhinav" so it actually changes the pipeline variable value to abhinav.

[image]

[image]

I want to update this variable through Powershell. I am using one PowerShell script calling the API and trying to update its variable but getting the page not found error:-

```
param(
[string]$winVersion
)
$body = "{ 'definition' : { 'id' :85}
}"
$valueName="Winver"
$definitionId=85
$User=""
$Password=""
$base64authinfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $Password)))
$Uri = "https://Muac.visualstudio.com/OSGCXE/_apis/release/releases?api-version=2.0"
$urlDef = "https://Muac.visualstudio.com/OSGCXE/_apis/release/definitions/" + $definitionId + "?api-version=2.0"
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authInfo)} -Method Get -Uri $urlDef 

#Write-Host $definition

$definition.variables.$valueName.Value = "$winVersion"
$definitionJson = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 50 -Compress

#Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json $definition -Depth 100)

$update=Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authInfo)} -Method Put -Uri $urlDef -Body $definitionJson -ContentType "application/json"

#Write-Host "$update"

#$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64authinfo)} -Body $body

#write-Host $buildresponse.status
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set an VSTS Build variable in a Build Step so that the value can be used in a subsequent Build Step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881749/is-it-possible-to-set-an-vsts-build-variable-in-a-build-step-so-that-the-value-c)

Comment: You can't put a new value to the variable like regular way, you need to follow the answer above.

Comment: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=winversion;]test" 
I also tried with that but nothing happens.
Write-Host "Main value is $(winversion)"
always print the first value 23  not test.

Comment: This is another link from Microsoft's docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer%2Cpowershell#set-in-script

Comment: i think it will only get updated in the next step, not in the same step

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How To set azure pipeline variable from PowerShell

There is a bit of confusion here, you use the variable `$winversion` in the powershell scripts, but the variable is set `testvar` in the pipeline variable.

Anyway, no matter we overwrite the pipeline variable value directly like you, or use the script `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"` to overwrite it, the overwrite value only work for current build pipeline. When you use the `$(winversion)` to get the value, it will still pull the value from pipeline variable value. To get the current value, you need use `$env:WINVERSION`.

Besides, you said:

> I want when I change the value of winversion from "123" to "abhinav"
>   so it actually changes the pipeline variable value to abhinav.

If you mean you want change the pipeline variable value on the **web portal**, you need the REST API ([Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body)) to update the value of the build pipeline definition variable from a build task.

There is a very similar thread, you can check the answer for the details:

[How to modify Azure DevOps release definition variable from a release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task/53060141#53060141)

Note:Change the API to the build definitions:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: variable name in pipeline is winversion

Comment: @AbhinavSharma, Ahah, It is my fault, very very sorry about this. You should use the API `PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.0` Check the document here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0. And as test, I could use Definitions - Get API to get all the release list.

Comment: Please look at my complete script in the question section i have added some more lines to my question.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma, To make sure we the path is correct, you can try to use postman to get a release definition by the get PAI:`GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0`, if we get the 200OK, then we change it to update API.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma, As I test with postman, we could not use the username/password to call that Rest API(401 Unauthorized). You can try to use PAT or Access OAuth Token to do it, check the details from this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399076/how-to-increase-update-variable-group-value-using-azure-devops-build-definition

Answer (score 2):

I found this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell

This has the complete options of what you can do:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

You can reuse set variable from task to task, and also job to job.
I couldn't find anything on stage to stage.

In summary:

```
jobs:

# Set an output variable from job A
- job: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value"
    name: setvarStep
  - script: echo $(setvarStep.myOutputVar)
    name: echovar

# Map the variable into job B
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]  # map in the variable
                                                                          # remember, expressions require single quotes
  steps:
  - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA)
    name: echovar
```

Comment: Well, to reuse variable in the same scope, you will be able to use a shorter syntax: `nugetConfigPath: "$(set_pipeline_vars_task.solution_dir_path)/NuGet.Config"`